# compare redis command: multi and mget

Tags: redis

there are two systems sharing a redis database, one system just read the redis, the other update it.

the read system is so busy that the redis can't handle it, to reduce the count of requests to redis, I find "mget", but I also find "multi".

1. I'm sure mget will reduce the number of requests, but will "multi" do the same? I think "multi" will force the redis server to keep some info about this transaction and collect requests in this transaction from the client one by one, so the total number of requests sent stays the same, but the results returned will be combined together, right?
2. So If I just read KeyA, keyB, keyC in "multi" when the other write system changed KeyB's value, what will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer: You should use `MGET`**

`MULTI` is used for transaction, and it won't reduces the number of requests. Also, the `MULTI` command **MIGHT** be deprecated in the future, since there's a better choice: `lua scripting`.

> 2. So If I just read KeyA, keyB, keyC in "multi" when the other write system changed KeyB's value, what will happen?

Since `MULTI` (with `EXEC`) command ensures transaction, all of the three `GET` commands (read operations) executes atomically. If the update happens before the read operation, you'll get the old value. Otherwise, you'll get the new value.

By the way, there's another option to reduce RTT: `PIPELINE`. However, in your case, `MGET` should be the best option.